# For getting describe attributes checks in aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lib

Here I am trying to get AWS limit check ids from `AWSLIMITCHECKER` module and from that I need to check `categorywise`.

This is my sample code:

```
from awslimitchecker.checker import AwsLimitChecker
from awslimitchecker.trustedadvisor import TrustedAdvisor
#from awslimitchecker.services.base import _AwsService

res = TrustedAdvisor(all_services={},
   region='my region',
   account_id='myacct id',
   account_role='my role'
)
```

Here I need to pass these params of all_services. What all do I need to pass in this dictionary?  How can I get check ids using function `_get_limit_check_id`.

Here is the reference link for `awslimitchecker`: https://awslimitchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/awslimitchecker/trustedadvisor.html#TrustedAdvisor._get_limit_check_id

I have checked boto api also,but whether is it possible to get check ids and checks of aws trusted advisor using awslimitcheckermodule itself?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
 Hi i have resolved this,but when i getting check ids it shows the following
```

error:

```
    mycode:

       d = TrustedAdvisor(services,
                 region='myregion',
                 account_id='none',
                 account_role='none'
     )




       e = d._get_limit_check_id()


error:

           File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-      packages/awslimitchecker/trustedadvisor.py", line 190, in _get_limit_check_id
             checks = self.conn.describe_trusted_advisor_checks(
              AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'describe_trusted_advisor_checks'
```

Comment: Any suggestion for the above describe_trusted_advisor_checks other than using botoapi?